# Does android support HFP bluetooth profile?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Does android support Bluetooth HFP profile ? Or is it device dependent ?.

What are the profiles supported by Android at the OS level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next profiles are natively supported by Android: A2DP, HFP, HSP. By "natively" I mean that Android is capable to stream audio to devices that support at least one of these profiles.

Handling of A2DP and HFP profiles is almost transparent to your application. You just play audio into STREAM_MUSIC and those devices will peek it up when connected.

Its much harder with HSP profile devices. Official API support for them was added in API Level 8 (Android 2.2) and you have to stream audio to STREAM_VOICE stream: see [AudioManager.startBluetoothSco](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#startBluetoothSco%28%29) for more details. But detecting whether HSP device is connect  was still officially unsupported (though there are workarounds for this).

In API Level 11 two new classes were introduced: [BluetoothHeadset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.html) and [BluetoothA2DP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothA2dp.html) which make life much easier. These two classes existed in android since API Level 3, but they were included in official API only in 11th release (though these classes were changed dramatically since the 3rd API Level).

Comment: I don't have a bluetooth audio device. I have device for tracking, that uses the HFP profile. So it can accept HFP profile commands. So is there a way to send commands to a HFP profile device that is not Bluetooth headset.

Comment: I haven't investigated that question. Android itself was able to handle commands from HFP (volume up/volume down), but this was definitely not exposed as of API Level 10. In API Level 11 `BluetoothHeadset` class was introduced and it has some constants that look like they are `CMD`s: `AT_CMD_TYPE_READ`, `AT_CMD_TYPE_SET`. But I wasn't yet able to find how to send/receive them. Though I just scanned the documentation and it might just be incomplete.